# Scripting - How to create a filter based on array length / size?

Tags: elasticsearch, mvel

I'm very new to ES but I'm trying to create a script that can query for an array to contain some matches but also filter based on the total array size.

Example data:

```
"_source": {
  "id": 5,
  "title": "Chicken & vegetable broth, soda farls & chicken liver toasts ",
  "ingredients": [
    "1 organic or free-range chicken",
    "5 large onions",
    "100g butter, for frying"
  ]
}
```

The following query would match the record above but would not return it because it has less than 5 ingredients.

```
{
"query": {
    "function_score": {
        "query": {
            "terms": {
                "ingredients": ["beef", "bacon"]
            }
        },
        "functions": [{
            "script_score": {
                "script": "ingredients-amount",
                "params": {
                    "my_modifier": 5
                }
            }
        }]
    }
  }
}
```

I thought `ingredients-amount.mvel` would simple be along the lines of:

```
doc['ingredients'].values.length > my_modifier
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index the length of the array, so you can do a simple `range`-filter.

If you use a script for this, you will be loading the *entire* field into memory, which you probably don't want to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it the script way, then the expression will be:

```
doc['ingredients'].values.size() > my_modifier
```

but using doc is indeed not the best, performance-wise, so you might be better off with indexing the length of the ingredients list as Alex suggested.